# Drupal 8, Some module's checkbox are disabled.

Tags: drupal-8

I'm a newbie in Drupal 8. I have a question about extends/modules.why are some modules checkbox disabled and I can't check themes.
[image]

As you could see, I can't check Mega Slider !!

Answer (score 1):

There may be two cases :-

1. The module is already enabled and you are unable to check because in drupal 8 you have another tab known uninstall to disable the module. Here you can check the module and disable the module for your website.

   [Please see the attached pic for uninstall tab in drupal 8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJfRn.png)
2. The module you are trying to check is disabled because it has some dependency of other modules to be enabled or uninstall first.